# Why does my Symfony application not use the correct database parameters when it's trying to show a page

Tags: php, database, symfony, phpmyadmin, doctrine

So I uploaded my Symfony (3.4) application with FTP on a shared host. The website loads, but whenever I try to load a page with a database request in it, I get error 500.

This is the error that shows in my prod.log:

> request.CRITICAL: Uncaught PHP Exception
>   Doctrine\DBAL\Exception\ConnectionException: "An exception occured in
>   driver: SQLSTATE[28000] [1045] Access denied for user
>   'root'@'127.0.0.1' (using password: YES)" at
>   /home/michemu313/domains/aested.nl/symfony/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver/AbstractMySQLDriver.php
>   line

With a SSH connection I can do Doctrine commands, so the database connection works. It looks like it's using the wrong parameters when loading up a page.

A bit of my parameters.yml

```
parameters:
    database_host: localhost
    database_port: null
    database_name: michemu313_aested
    database_user: USERNAME
    database_password: PASSWORD
```

So far I've tried to set the parameters in the .htaccess without success. Also tried to put in the app.php without success.

(I've had another application without Symfony running on the same server with the same parameters so those are correct.)

Comment: Have you tried to clear the production cache? Also set the database_port to the actual port you are using (typically 3306 for mysql)

Comment: Does Doctrine actually use these parameters (look in `config.yaml` under `doctrine->dbal`)?

Answer (score 0):

Just make sure that your have the right USERNAME / Password to access MySQL database. With a shared host, you should put a config like this:

```
parameters:
    database_host: ftp.your-shared-host-domain.com
    database_port: 3306  ## if you are using MySQL
    database_name: michemu313_aested
    database_user: RIGHT_USERNAME
    database_password: RIGHT_PASSWORD
```

Comment: I do have the right username and password, and I added the right port (3306.) But it seems like it's still using the wrong parameters.

Answer (score -1):

I had to clear the cache and I added some of the database parameters directly into Symfony's config.yml.